# If / else statement in wordpress to change uploaded image to default

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement

I have some trouble with changing image on default one when the image field is empty. Here the two different images. I want to combine them and if get_field('author_photo') is empty then upload the second one.

```
  <?php 
       $image = get_field('author_photo');
       if( !empty($image) ): 
  ?>

  <img src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" height="80" id="img-sp" alt="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>" />

  <?php endif; ?>              

  <? if (get_user_featured_image_id('mentor','user_'.get_the_author_ID())){ ?>
  <?php $image = p_get_attachment_image_src(get_field('user_featured_image', 'user_'.get_the_author_ID()),'small-profile-thumbnail'); 
  ?>

  <img src="<?php echo @$image[0]; ?>" height="80"  alt="" id="img-sp"/>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm trying to read your question but I can't stop staring at the @$image call. Never, ever, ever use @. It's suppressing something you should know. Even with it suppressed the warning will cause unnecessary and unexpected system load. Now I'll read through this @_@

Comment: Shouldnt the line be this = <img src="<?php echo @$image; ?>" height="80"  alt="" id="img-sp"/>

Comment: Where's the ending { for the second if? I don't see it. Also, if you ever have ?><?php, you are just making things more complicated to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it yesterday. Thank you for your answers.

```
<?php
   $image = get_field('author_photo');
    $src_link = "";
    $alt_text = "";

    if (!empty($image)) {
        $src_link = $image['url'];
        $alt_text = $image['alt'];
    } elseif (get_user_featured_image_id('mentor','user_'.get_the_author_ID())) {
        $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_user_featured_image_id('mentor','user_'.get_the_author_ID()),'small-profile-thumbnail');
        $src_link = @$image[0];
    }

    if ($src_link) { ?>
        <img src="<?php echo $src_link; ?>" height="80" id="img-sp" alt="<?php echo $alt_text; ?>" /><?php
    }
?>
```